# Zabbix: The history of the metric is not displayed on all timeframes

Tags: zabbix, metrics

There is a metric (in this case, the temperature of the router). On timeframes from minutes to the last two days, everything is displayed correctly, all data is in place.

[image]

When I try to view the metric for the last 3 days, week, month and up to 3 months, it says "no data" and nothing is displayed.

[image]

When I switch to 6 months and then to a year or more, everything also displays correctly.

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem and how is it possible? In the storage settings, I have specified to store metrics for the last year

[image]